# Mystery sequence ïz£ in pdf

Tags: input-encodings

I get random copies of a sequence ïz£ (an "i" with the umlaut, a "z" with a dot sign over it, and a pounds sign) in my pdf. They seem to be generated by some of the figures, not all. Any suggestion?

Comment: (1) Welcome, (2) without any code or examples of how that figure is made we cannot say for sure. It might be because the data is not in the right encoding, but again without access to the details we have no idea.

Comment: it is probably a UTF-8 file that you are reading as an 8-bit encoding, most common is ï»¿ at the start of a file which is a UTF-8 byte order mark, viewed as latin-1

Comment: (1) Thank you. (2) Thank you. It worked (though via a roundabout way to get rid of the ï»¿.

Answer (score 1):

This is fairly common if there is a change of code page.  I should look carefully at what the code page is in the source document and down the path.  I used to get it a bit when winedt loaded ANSI pages in Unicode.

Comment: Thank you (see above)